# Referencing to figures & sourcecode in appendix (Numbering issue)

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, lstlisting, appendix

during the main part of my paper I reference to the appendix like so:

```
\footnote{\textit{\ref{fig:graphqlSchema} \nameref{fig:graphqlSchema} (S. \pageref{fig:graphqlSchema})}}
```

or so:

```
\footnote{\textit{\ref{lst:sthElse} \nameref{lst:sthElse} (S. \pageref{lst:sthElse})}}
```

The correct labels are set in the appendix after the caption.

The Problem is that in the footnote it says both times A.1 "Caption Text". I want something like Sourcecode A.1 and Table A.1 automatically.

Thank you vermy much!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I think you just want `\autoref` instead of `\nameref` (assuming you are loading `hyperref`. `\nameref` is **supposed** to provide you with the text of the caption.

Comment: You can take a look at the `cleveref` package. It will help you "vermy much"!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
\autoref
```

Did the job for me.

Thank you, Paul!